# load UITableView from parse query

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

This code works part of the time,and other times it returns an empty array.I don't know why.I'm calling it in `viewWillAppear` .

```
func refreshFriendListFromLocalDatastore() {
    println("refreshing from local datastore")
    var friendRelations:PFRelation = currentUser.relationForKey("friendRelations") as PFRelation
    var query:PFQuery = friendRelations.query() as PFQuery
    query.orderByAscending("username")
    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (NSArray friends, NSError error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.friends = friends
            println("\(self.friends)")
            tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            println("could not retrieve friend list at this time")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try looking at `error` when it doesn't work?

Comment: There's no error that prints on the console. It just returns an empty array, as shown through the println

Comment: What's an empty string? `friends` is an array. What does the `error` variable say when this happens?

Comment: My apologies, that was a typo on my part. I'll check the error variable now

Comment: @AaronBrager the error variable is printing as "nil" when the empty array is returned

Answer (score 0):

`currentUser` has no friend relationships with users who have been pinned to the local data store using `pin`.

Comment: That doesn't make sense because it loads half of the time

Comment: I can toggle back and forth between the view, and sometimes it loads and sometimes it doesn't